# How can I get the latest Java version jre-7u45 to work on Win8 with IE10

Tags: windows-8, java

I have Windows 8 and recently upgraded to internet explorer 10.  (For some reason I can't connect to the windows store to obtain Win 8.1.  I keep getting a message telling me to try later, but that's not the problem I want to address at the moment.)  My problem is with internet explorer 10 and Java.  After upgrading my IE, I also needed to upgrade java in order to play games on a site named Pogo.  I installed the latest java version, jre-7u45-windows-i586.exe but the Java test page doesn't verify the new Java version nor does the Pogo site I use recognize it to be working.  I have gone through all of the troubleshooting I can find with no success.  I even tried installing jre-6u37 because a year ago, someone somewhere had Win 8 64 bit like me and found this version of java to work.  It didn't work for me.  If someone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having an issue with the 64 bit version of Java (Does it say in Control Panel, then click Java, which version it is?)

Try the 32 bit version of 7u45 if you are in fact on the 64 bit:

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u45-b18/jre-7u45-windows-i586.exe

Also, Java is kind of notorious for having issues as it reinstalls over old versions. Try completely uninstalling, rebooting, then reinstalling clean.

---

If that still doesn't work, try uninstalling, then rebooting, then run this (JavaRa is designed to clean out old version of Java and all associated files):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javara/

.. then reboot, then install from scratch.